# OR operation on all bit array member on a vector of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a class Item with a vector of another class SubItem.
SubItem class has a bit array that stores subItem's states. Each state of subitem class is set/reset independent of other states and other subItems. The states are set/reset in an event driven environment.

I want to create a state in Item class also that depends on an OR operation of subItem's states i-e if ANY of the subItems's state, for example,  State1=1 then Item's state1=1 and if ALL of the subitems state1=0 then item's state1=0.

The complication is, the subitem vector size in Item class can be large and I dont want to loop through all SubItems to set the Item's states whenever subitem's state changes.

One option is I make an array of ints in Item and keep a count of how many legs have a given state set to 1 and whenever the count is 0 I know all subItem's state1 is set to 0 so I can set Item's state1 also to 0. This however is not space efficient.

I had another solution in mind but dont know how to do it without looping through subItems.
The solution is that Item also has a bitarray. So to decide if ITem's state1=1 I get the state1 of all legs and do an OR with a const unsigned int = 0 (00000000) if the result of this OR operation is a non-zero then I know item's state1 is also 1 and when the result is 0 then item's state1 is also 0 but I just dont know how to do it without looping through all the subItems whenever a subitem's state is modified.

```
//this enum refers to subitem's and item's states
    enum class flags 
    {
    state1, state2, state3, state4
    }   


    class SubItem
    {    
//The bitarray that stores states of subItem  
  unsigned int bitarray;
    }

    Class Item
    {
    std:vector<SubItem> m_arrSubItems;    
    Item(size_t size)
    {
    m_arrSubItems.Reserve(size)
    }
    /*The Item wants to create an array of states here.Each index of this array is an OR operation of the same state across all SubItems.*/
    }
```

Comment: "This however is not space efficient." => with only one int per state ?

Comment: there are about 30 states but also it is very easy for a developer to forget to update item's state count when toggling subitem's state. I may go with this count option if I dont find any other better option

Comment: Yes the problem with this option is not space but code maintenance. Are you sure you're having a problem in the first place, i.e. does looping results in mesurable performance problems ?

Comment: yes. we talking about hundreds of times per second and its a batch processing of a long list of items on a single thread.

Comment: OK, but did you actually measure it in a worst-case scenario ? NB on average you're not looping through all subItems, you stop as soon as you've found 2 different states.

Comment: but I still want to know if there is a better way todo that without looping on each state change.

Answer (score 0):

> One option is I make an array of ints in Item and keep a count of how
>   many legs have a given state set to 1 and whenever the count is 0 I
>   know all subItem's state1 is set to 0 so I can set Item's state1 also
>   to 0. This however is not space efficient.

It is space-efficient (only one counter per state to add), but you'd have to make sure that the bit-set operation can only be done through a function that sets the bit and also change the corresponding counter, to keep everything in sync.

Otherwise, the only other option I see is to delegate the counting to a data structure, but for that you would have to change the way the bits are stored. For instance, using two sets of integers for each state, one for items with bit=1 and another for items with bit = 0 - but using that particular structure would use (a lot) more memory and probably also be slower.

> I had another solution in mind but dont know how to do it without looping through subItems. The solution is that Item also has a
>   bitarray. So to decide if ITem's state1=1 I get the state1 of all legs
>   and do an OR with a const unsigned int = 0 (00000000) if the result of
>   this OR operation is a non-zero then I know item's state1 is also 1
>   and when the result is 0 then item's state1 is also 0 but I just dont
>   know how to do it without looping through all the subItems whenever a
>   subitem's state is modified.

I don't see how that could solve the problem (and `x OR 0` is alxays `x`, so what's the point ?).

PS and before spending any time making your code more complex, you should profile your process to see if the counting from the vector is *actually* an issue. It might only eat 0.1% of the total processing time.